# Javascript: onClick => scroll different element?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a scrollable container.

On the bottom of this container is a gradient.

I want to be able to use a touch screen and scroll down when I put my finger on the gradient like if the gradient isn't there. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: See this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch

Comment: You can do this a number of ways but the property to set it the scrollTop of the scrollable container.